# Can't Filter NULLS in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I'm using a Moodle DB. I don't want any NULL values to show up in my query. But so far it's not working:

```
SELECT mdl_user.department, mdl_user.id, mdl_user.username, mdl_user.firstname, mdl_user.lastname, mdl_course_completions.course, mdl_course_completions.timecompleted, mdl_course.fullname  

FROM mdl_user LEFT JOIN (mdl_course_completions, mdl_course) ON (mdl_user.id = mdl_course_completions.id AND mdl_course_completions.id = mdl_course.id) WHERE NOT (mdl_course_completions.timecompleted IS NULL);\G
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

I tried using IS NOT NULL, but that gave me the same results.

Any ideas???

Comment: Do you get any results if you remove the WHERE?

Comment: how about not a left join, or is not null of a certain column

Comment: You can try using inner join instead of left join

Comment: are you doing the joins properly? you're joing two different tables on the same `mdl_course_completions.id`, which doesn't make much sense. foreign keys usually relate to only ONE table, not two different ones. Otherwise that implies `mdl_user.id = mdl_course.id` are the same field

Comment: Try doing WHERE  (mdl_course_completions.timecompleted IS NOT NULL);

Comment: Can you add the table schemas?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'd more or less expect:

```
SELECT mdl_user.department, mdl_user.id, mdl_user.username,
    mdl_user.firstname, mdl_user.lastname, mdl_course_completions.course,
    mdl_course_completions.timecompleted, mdl_course.fullname  
FROM mdl_user
LEFT JOIN mdl_course_completions ON mdl_user.id = mdl_course_completions.user_id 
LEFT JOIN mdl_course ON mdl_course_completions.course_id = mdl_course.id)
WHERE mdl_course_completions.timecompleted IS NOT NULL
```

assuming that `mdl_course_completions` has foreign keys `user_id` to `mdl_user(id)` and `course_id` to `mdl_course(id)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    mdl_user.department, 
    mdl_user.id, 
    dl_user.username,
    mdl_user.firstname, 
    mdl_user.lastname, 
    mdl_course_completions.course,
    mdl_course_completions.timecompleted, 
    mdl_course.fullname  
FROM mdl_user
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM mdl_course_completions WHERE timecompleted IS NOT NULL) as mdl_course_completions
    ON mdl_user.id = mdl_course_completions.user_id 
LEFT JOIN mdl_course 
    ON mdl_course_completions.id = mdl_course.id
```

As the other user suggested, "mdl_user.id = mdl_course_completions.id" doesn't look right "user_id = user_id" I'm assuming the id of mdl_course_completions is not that of a user?